# Split data on different users: multi-criteria optimization?

Tags: classification, sampling, optimization, train-test-split

I have data for binary classification (red/non-red). The data comes from different users with ids 1-N. Data from different ids have a) different distributions of red examples and also b) different number of examples. The first table illustrates this.

```
id  #     red
1   100   .3
2   200   .1
3   100   .166
==================
total: 400
weighted avg: 0.165
```

I need to split the the dataset - create two samples containing all the data. Each of the samples should:

**a)** contain data from distinct ids,
**b)** have ratio of 1:M in number of
examples (1:3 for example), and
**c)** have the same distribution of red
examples (= same as the weighted average of all examples).

The desired result (M=3) could look like this:

```
ids    sample  #     weighted avg of red
1,2    1       300   0.1667
3      2       100   0.166
```

What algorithms could solve this? I have limited knowledge of optimization algorithms but I think this is called multi-criteria optimization (we optimize for two things: example count and red ratio). However, the theory is vast and I don't know where to start.